# User/Group Folder permissions

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, ftp

This is confusing me a lot, I followed suggestions from a lot of answers here and for some reason it is still not working at all. Please bear with me as I explain what is happening.

I have a folder located at `/home/admin/shared`, I want to give a group called `developers` access (read and write) to this specific folder.

I have created the group and set it as the owner of the folder with this:

```
sudo chgrp -R developers /home/admin/shared
```

I then run `ls -l /home/admin` to check who owns the folder:

```
drwxrwxrwx  7 admin developers 4096 Dec 20 19:10  shared
```

I even check what groups my user is part of with

```
groups {username}
```

And it's right.

However both from SSH and FTP Client (Filezilla), every time I try to move to `/home/admin/shared`, I receive a `permission denied` error.

I've tried to use chmod too, but with the same results.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Kept trying without any luck.

I ended up creating a third folder `/home/shared` and then making the `developers` group owner of that and it started working fine.

I'd still like to know if there's a fix to my original question though.